# How to rearrange columns in python DataFrame (python3)

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm loading quite big excel sheets to dataframe and I need to rearrange columns in some elegant way so my coworker could use this data in her SPSS script which is already written.

I know that it's as easy as passing list of column indexes, but my Dataframe has 115 data columns so it's a long list. That's why I'm looking for a elegant way to rearrange columns as follows (zero indexed):

**columns 0 to 8, columns 10 to 112, column 9, column 113 to 114**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
columns = list(df.columns)
df = df[columns[:9]+columns[10:113]+[columns[9]]+columns[113:]]
```

Note that, to go from `10 -> 112`, you need `columns[10:113]` because the slicer doesn't consider the last element as part of the interval

Comment: Thank You, I thought it will be something like this :)